# Swift time being returned as am when it is pm

Tags: swift, nsdate

This function gets current time and finds the next time in an array. When the current time is before midday and the next time is after midday, it returns the next time as am when it should be pm.
How can I change this? Would I need to use a 12 hour clock instead of a 24 hour clock?

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

let date = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = calendar.components([.Hour, .Minute], fromDate: date)
let hour = components.hour
let minutes = components.minute
let currentTime = "\(hour)" + ":" + "\(minutes)"  //output 10:47


let timesArray = ["5:45", "6:35", "7:00", "7:30", "7:50", "8:20", "8:40", "9:15", "10:10",
    "12:40", "14:15", "14:50", "15:40", "16:10", "17:10", "17:40", "18:40", "19:25", "20:50"]

// create a method to convert your time to minutes
func stringToMinutes(input:String) -> Int {
    let components = input.componentsSeparatedByString(":")
    let hour = Int((components.first ?? "0")) ?? 0
    let minute = Int((components.last ?? "0")) ?? 0
    return hour*60 + minute
}

//create an array with the minutes from the original array
let timesMinutesArray:[Int] = timesArray.map { stringToMinutes($0) }

let dayMinute = stringToMinutes(currentTime)
// filter out the times that has already passed
let filteredTimesArray = timesMinutesArray.filter{$0 > dayMinute }

// get the first time in your array
if let firstTime = filteredTimesArray.first {
    // find its position and extract it from the original array
    let nextDeparture = timesArray[timesMinutesArray.indexOf(firstTime)!]   // output  "12:40"


    let userCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()


    let dateMakerFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateMakerFormatter.calendar = userCalendar
    dateMakerFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"



    // How many hours and minutes between current time and next departure?

    dateMakerFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm"
    let startTime = dateMakerFormatter.dateFromString(currentTime)!
    let endTime = dateMakerFormatter.dateFromString(nextDeparture)! //this comes back as 12:40 am not pm
    let hourMinuteComponents: NSCalendarUnit = [.Hour, .Minute]
    let timeDifference = userCalendar.components(
        hourMinuteComponents,
        fromDate: startTime,
        toDate: endTime,
        options: [])

    let difference = (timeDifference.hour*60) + (timeDifference.minute)


}
```

Comment: See: [Date Field SymbolTable.](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Comment: How do you see the time with am/pm? I don't with: `print("endTime: \(endTime)")`, I get: "endTime: 2000-01-01 19:50:00 +0000".

Comment: not sure.. let endTime = dateMakerFormatter.dateFromString(nextDeparture)!       output =  "Jan 1, 2000, 12:40 PM"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a capital H in your `dateFormat`:

```
dateMakerFormatter.dateFormat = "H:mm"
```

Comment: H: Hour [0-23]. When used in skeleton data or in a skeleton passed in an API for flexible date pattern generation, it should match the 24-hour-cycle format preferred by the locale (H or k); it should not match a 12-hour-cycle format (h or K).